# Images of measurable function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

My question is as follows. Consider an $L^\infty$ function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that, for almost all $y$, the function $f({\cdot}, y)$ is continuous.

$\DeclareMathOperator\conv{conv}$Let $\conv D$ stand for the closed convex hull of a set $D$ and let $B_r(x)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be the open ball
with radius $r>0$ and with center at $x$.

I want to write
$$\bigcap_{r,r'>0}\bigcap_N\conv f(B_r(x_0),B_{r'}(y_0)\setminus N)=\bigcap_{r'>0}\bigcap_N\conv f(x_0,B_{r'}(y_0)\backslash N).$$
Here $\bigcap_N$ stands for the intersection over all measure-$0$ sets $N\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.
I feel that there must be some uniform continuity  conditions on $f$ for this equality to be valid but I do not understand what to do.

Comment: This is stated in a way that makes it look like a homework question.  Is it one?  If so, then it doesn't belong here.

Comment: How does it arise?  Do you know that it is true in any particular, non-convex case?

Comment: Oleg: the software on this website seems to think you are two different people.  Can you comment using the same computer or browser window as you used to write the question?